# Would a 4000-year-old booby trap still be poisonous?

Tags: time, poisons, dungeons

I've got a group of characters exploring an ancient ruin who've just set off a classic "darts flying from the walls" booby trap. In theory, when the trap was first built these darts would have been coated in poison (something adjacent to spider venom). But since it's been 4000 years, would that still be the case? Or would any kind of organic material coating these darts have long-since dried up, or eroded away, or lost its potency?

Comment: Snap answer would be "yes, any organic venom would long since have denatured".  But you have inorganic options.  Rather than darts, why not a shower of arsenic powder?

Comment: I recommend a deep pit, or a stone dropped on the thief's head. I can assure you that *gravity* will still work 4,000 years later.

Comment: Why is a sufficient quantity of darts not potentially lethal *without* poison?  A dart in the head is always going to put a crimp in your day.

Comment: The conditions in the ruin might help: Freezing temperatures and darkness slow most chemical reactions to a crawl. (The cold also degrade the poison, but if the original chemist / poisoner was choosing a poison to work in the cold, they might get something long-lived without specifically deciding to do that.) If you've got some reason to justify an airtight seal around the poison, that could help as well. "Store it in a cool dry place" See also naturally-occurring mummies, which would degrade by the same processes as your poison: https://www.iceman.it/en/the-iceman/

Comment: *"Plutonium may give you grief for thousands of years, but arsenic is forever."*

Comment: There are viruses that are emerging after being trapped in the ice for 30,000 years.  They are still infectious.

Comment: Only if you eat it, inhale it, or rub it on your skin. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poison Would a 4000-year-old booby trap still be *toxic*?

Comment: holy crap great question! haha this sure puts a lot of adventure films to shame if answered negatively

Comment: After 4000 years, would the (presumably) wooden darts still be deadly, or powder?

Comment: @WalterMitty thats just in the movies. 1918 flu was recovered with extreme difficulty via genetic engineering

Comment: @GCCampbell They could be bronze or obsidian

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Maybe, if chosen carefully

Very, very few organic molecules other than hydrocarbons and simple molecules are stable for more than a century or two under normal conditions.

The very few molecules and materials (e.g. cellulose) that are close to completely stable still suffer from:

1. photoreactions and radical reactions if exposed to any amount of light. Even sitting on crystalline silicates is bad on a timescale of thousands of years due to photoreactions.
2. slow evaporation
3. slow hydrolysis, often catalytic, so tiny amounts of water will do it
4. biologically mediated damage
5. very slow catalysed reactions with trace impurities.

However, with all that said, if you actually set out to make something poisonous in a few thousand years, you could do it.

Potassium cyanide won't go away and is an obvious choice.
Heavy metals won't go away.
Various radioactive isotopes will be as bad or worse than they started.

Closer in spirit to your spider venom:
One can imagine some maniacal Atlantean*  chemist making polymerised toxins (botulin? sarin? other nerve agents?) that are thus stabilised and break down back into the poison itself slowly over thousands of years.

The monomer would need to have a relatively simple, compact structure with no really funky functional groups.

(EDIT: depending on your fictional world's history. Not an option in real life).

Comment: My first thought was elemental toxins, but the dosage requirement tends to be high. While in the modern world we can make some radioactive nasties, the ancients cannot.

Comment: @Joshua Depends on who the ancients are and what they know. It actually does not take much in the way of modern technology to produce dangerously radioactive materials, it’s just dangerous to do without modern technology. But in a lot of ancient cultures, that would not have mattered, they’d just use slaves to do the dangerous parts.

Comment: I thought of cyanide but it looks like the CN will oxidize eventually.    I want to believe.  Can you link up info on perpetual cyanide?

Comment: Also don't discount that while the poison might not have aged well, the tips might still contain inorganic compounds that can mess with the human body or be crawling with all sorts of infectious microbes.

Comment: Maybe the trick is in the container design to achieve that complete dryness; if it's completely free of water, and is possible, oxygen, things get much easier. Maybe a container with 1) one solid compound that will reliably scavenge oxygen and water, 2) one that will gradually break down into nitrogen (so as to not have to maintain a vacuum), 3) Our toxin, not in contact with the other compounds. KCN under nitrogen in the dark, with no bacteria or fungi, would have no way to decompose. Even disproportionation would be thermodynamically forbidden.Of course, then lots of other options come back.

Comment: @Willk, I just thought this through again. KCN will be fine as long as the container is dry (not perfect 100.000% dry, just normal 100% if rounded dry) and airtight. Consider mass balance. If you have 2g of KCN, there simply won't be enough oxygen to oxidise the KCN. Thermodynamic considerations rule out any other degradation path.

Comment: @SeanOConnor - A glass ampule could keep out water and O2 for 4000 years.  Maybe an ampule that breaks on impact with the dark behind it?

Comment: @Willk Yes, that's much better. I think Slarty here suggested it before my comment re chamber design.

Comment: I'm just thinking scored/barbed glass coating around the dart. keeps out chemicals that would degrade poison/toxins, but would add extra lacerations when it shatters on impact or upon attempts at removal

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn this doesn't change the fact that anything radioactive enough to be deadly (or seriously harmful) in dosage ranges below heavy metals will NOT be that radioactive anymore after four thousand years.

Answer (score 16):

## Fill the [floor with hematite](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-2000-sep-16-mn-21968-story.html)

This is a yellow powder, an oxide of iron. It's extremely common and long lasting. The Egyptians coated their floors with it. It rips apart the lungs and softer tissues. When the darts hit they'll likely move quickly or fall over, stirring up the dust and making their lives much more painful.

It doesn't decay since it's stable, so it can last 4000 years easily, just as the Egyptian version did.

Comment: Hematite isn't yellow, it is grey or reddish.. It [is quite unpleasant](https://consult.environment-agency.gov.uk/psc/tr3-6ee-uk-remediation-ltd/supporting_documents/Supporting%20Documents%20%20Part%20B3%20Q3c%20%20MDS%20Sheers%20for%20Raw%20Materials%20%20Iron%20III%20Oxide%20Anhydrous%20MSDS.pdf) if you eat or inhale the dust, but, y'know... don't snort or lick the tomb dust, ok? A decent layered face covering will protect, and initial exposure is unlikely to be fatal or even debilitating for long.

Comment: The color depends on the microstructure, as does how toxic it is.

Comment: @StarfishPrime yeah, but you can also have a helmet and shoulderpads thick enough to block any falling arrows (since actual shooting mechanisms won't survive 4k years). The traps are bypasseable, yes. But you have to actually do it, wear the safety equipment (and in case of Hematite dust also decontaminate once outside).

Answer (score 14):

### Make the dart alive

As you suspected, no organic poison will stay stable for thousands of years. If Atlanteans want to use an organic poison, they need to refresh it once in a while... or let it refresh on its own.

Imagine a colony of poison-producing bacteria, fungi, lichen or such, growing on the dart. A species, that [already lives underground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endolith), will be able to grow also within the trap. Many underground organisms also have [very slow metabolic rate](https://www.forbes.com/sites/linhanhcat/2019/08/13/bacteria-has-metabolism-1-million-times-slower-eats-centuries-old-food/), that will help them survive for a very long time.

The organisms can be poisonous on their own (when they are inserted into the body through a wound). Or they can produce poisonous molecules and deposit them in their environment. Layers and layers of deposited poison could arguably make the trap **more** dangerous now, than it was when it was built.

If Atlantean architects are worried about their poison-producers running out of water or energy, they can drill a narrow chimney to occasionally deliver new material. That gives them a wider selection of poison producers, that can survive in their trap. We know that works even for more complex organisms [like ants](https://www.sciencealert.com/ants-trapped-in-an-old-soviet-nuclear-bunker-survived-for-years-by-turning-on-their-own).

Answer (score 10):

**Tetanus?**

https://www.cdc.gov/tetanus/about/causes-transmission.html

[image: tetnaus]

[source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DZkH0AeIk9DI&psig=AOvVaw0BlzS7pQ1EG0ZFZkq8aBlm&ust=1671034926762000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA8QjRxqFwoTCMD0v6yA9_sCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD)

This would not be the intent of the builders.  But darts bursting out of rat nests or other dirty stuff could cause a dirty wound and tetanus.  Lockjaw is weird and horrible and if it has been used in a fiction I have not read it.

That seizure comes with terminal tetanus. It is called "opisthonos".  It is an attention getter.
https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/318868

Comment: This only works if the characters have not been vaccinated for tetanus.

Comment: most people are vaccinated against tetanus these days

Comment: @njzk2 - very excellently true in our world in most places.  But not everywhere.  https://ourworldindata.org/tetanus#in-which-countries-do-people-still-die-from-tetanus

Comment: thanks for the link! I had no idea it was so recent!

Comment: Tetanus is not reliably four thousand years stable though

Comment: @Hobbamok - yeah.  This would be fresh tetanus on an old trap.

Answer (score 6):

4000 years would probably be enough to degrade most organic poisons via oxidation, hydrolysis, temperature and moisture cycling through the days and seasons etc in the open.

But if the intention from the beginning was to design a trap that would last a very long time then it should be possible. The best option would be a glass tube filled with poison under nitrogen gas with one end heated and drawn out into a long point and sealed. The tube could then be coated in something to keep the light out or it simply could be mechanically hidden in the dark.

Many poisons would be able to retain their potency for very extended periods under these conditions. The pointed nature of the tube if attached to some form of heavy swinging device should prove deadly.

Poisons like Strychnine or Ricin or nerve agents

Answer (score 4):

I note that the Chinses historians claimed that the unexcavated tomb of Qin Shih Huang, First Emperor of China (d. 210 BC) contained booby traps, crossbows rigged to shoot intruders.

The legends also claimed that the tomb had a giant map of Chinas with rivers and seas of liquid mercury.  And studies of the tomb area indicate an abnormally high concentration of mercury.  Obviously when the tomb is explored sometime in the future the archaeologists will have to take precautions against mercury poisoning, and maybe wear armor to protect from crossbow bolts.

So possibly the ruin in the story combines both features and contains booby traps of automatic crossbows dipped in liquid mercury or with arrowheads made of a toxic alloy of mercury.

Or maybe a booby trap will use a device to push the intruders off a ledge into a pool of poisonous liquid mercury.  People who fall into a pool of liquid mercury might swallow a lot of it.

Comment: Mercury is very, very, very, very, very, *very* dense. So dense, you could theoretically stand on a pool of it. I'd be more worried about getting a concussion then swallowing some. That said, mercury also vaporizes readily, so there would be a thick cloud of mercury fumes over this theoretical pool - and inhalation works a lot faster than ingestion.

Comment: The story of Emperor Qin's (pronounced Chin) tomb being surrounded in lake of mercury has pretty much proven from external measurements of the tomb site. However, the amount of wealth required in the ancient world to accumulate that amount of mercury is extraordinary.

Answer (score 3):

### Make the darts barbed and covered with mud

What if you start with (1) barbed darts, (2) dipped in poison (3) dried (4) dipped in mud or clay or other impervious coating (5) dry the coating? The premise here is that the crunchy outer coating protects against oxidation and moisture. When the barbed darts get stuck in someone's body, coating gets broken and the poison is dissolved in bodily fluids.

4000 years is a long time for an organic molecule to survive. Especially in a tropical climate. If your climate is temperate, the ruins could be arranged so that they're a lot cooler. Either underground or behind VERY thick walls. I don't know what the phenomenon is called, but once you get more than 4 ft underground or behind walls, the temperature is close to the average temperature for the whole year, day or night.

Cooler temperatures will slow down the decay of your poison.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, no organic compound would stay stable trough centuries. So you should go for inorganic ones.

**Mercury!**

It's not hard to work with. In fact, we have [examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(element)#Historic_uses) of mercury usage that are millenia old. And it cannot spoil, so it's toxicity won't degrade. And it is extremely toxic, especially if you use some compound forms of it. If you put it into glass containers (for example, in dart tips) you won't even have an issue with mercury evaporation. Or, if you are feeling particulary nasty, go for vapor route. In a sealed tomb that contain a large enough pool of mercury whole atmosphere would be toxic because of mercury vapors. And since tomb was sealed it won't run out.

Comment: Mercury metal is not very toxic. You can swallow a medical thermometer's worth of mercury with no serious ill effects. Mercury salts, on the other hand, are nasty. You really don't want to be injected with Mercuric Chloride. Methylmercury is one of the nastiest toxins known to man. The main barrier to an ancient alchemist synthesizing it, is that he'd probably kill himself horribly before working out what he had done! Also, it's volatile, so it might not persist where it was put for millennia.

Comment: @nigel222 Methylmercury was the first thing that came to mind reading the question.  I do agree there's no way ancients could have survived making it, though.

Comment: Organomercury compounds will surely disproportionate into mercury and hydrocarbons even if sealed away. They're extremely reactive. The simple salts are probably not toxic enough.

Comment: @nigel222 it wouldn't persist on it's own, but in easily-breakable flasks on the tips of arrows? As long as they remain sealed they're good for millenia and the lingering poison will likely suffice to kill even the second body-retrieval group

Comment: And who cares if the makers of those poisons die? That's what slaves are for! Or zealots.

Comment: @Negdo Yeah, that was my thought "Super toxic chemicals that will even kill you through a rubber glove? That's what lab slaves are for!" https://www.acsh.org/news/2016/06/06/two-drops-of-death-dimethylmercury